# Bottleneck - PCIe gen 3 x1 device on PCIe gen2 x2 slot

Tags: pci-express, hardware-rec

Is there a bottleneck between a device with PCIe gen 3 x1 connection
if connected to a PCIe gen2 x2 slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCIe x1 means that you have (or your card has) only one lane available. As one side of your connection is "x1" then you are limited to 1 lane.

The PCIe generation defines the maximum supported speed per lane, per the PCIe spec. A PCIe Gen 2 motherboard cannot work at Gen 3 speeds because it lacks the necessary (newer) hardware to do so.

As a result your card will be limited to PCIe Gen 2 x1 as it only has one lane available.

This means [you are limited to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) 500 MB/s (PCIe V2 x1) instead of 985 MB/s (PCIe V3 x1).

Whether that is an actual bottleneck depends on what the card is and how much data you expect to put through it every second. For a video capture card (~50Mbit/s for FullHD h.264) or sound card (1-2MB/s), even a gigabit network card (1Gbps or 125MB/s), this speed is fine.

Comment: The question is about PCIe gen2 x2, is it naive to say that I am limited to 2x500 MB/s?

Comment: You said your device is PCIe 3 x1 so you are limited by that too. You are limited to the lowest gen and number of lanes which means you are limited to Gen 2 x1. The "x1" denotes physical wiring of lanes to the port/card and you cannot just use more lanes because of slower speeds, the connections are physically not present on one side.